# How do I look inside a column in a CacheDataset in TensorFow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

**The following code was used to split the train and test set:**

```
tf.random.set_seed(42)
shuffled = ratings.shuffle(100_000, seed=42, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

train = shuffled.take(80_000)
test = shuffled.skip(80_000).take(20_000) # test is a _TakeDataset
```

**after building the model, there's the following code:**

```
cached_train = train.shuffle(100_000).batch(8_192).cache()
cached_test = test.batch(4_096).cache() # cached_test is a CacheDataset
```

**I'm trying to look at the values inside the column for 'User_ID' for 'cached_test', how can I do this? when printing 'cached_test', it gives the following line:**

```
<CacheDataset element_spec={'Name': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None), 'User_ID': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None), 'Rating': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)}>
```

essentially, I'm trying to do this if this was a pandas dataframe:

```
cached_test.head(5) or convert to_csv (if possible)
```

thank you!